# In correct query string append to retrofit request in android

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, build.gradle, retrofit2

I am trying to pass "**test+data**" to Retrofit api call but during api request process it is processing as "**test%2Bdata**". Due to this my API request is failing.

How to pass exact text to retrofit call?

i am trying with below code.

### build.gradle:

```
            buildConfigField("String", "api_type", "\"test+data\"")
```

### Repository:

```
    apiService.getAllData(BuildConfig.api_type)).enqueue(object : Callback<User> {
    override fun onResponse(call: Call<User>, response: Response<User>) {
    }

    override fun onFailure(call: Call<User>, t: Throwable) {
       
    }
});
```

### ApiService:

```
@GET("/?format=json")
fun getAllData(@Query("q") q: String) : Call<User>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add  'encoded = true'  to the @Query annotation, like this:

```
@Query("q" , encoded = true)
```